# Pytorch CPU and GPU run in parallel

Tags: deep-learning, gpu, pytorch

Is there a way to do something with CPU (compute mean and variance of current mini-batch loss) while GPU is doing back-propagation?

Something like this:

```
for input, label in dataloader:
  output = model(input)
  losses = some_loss_function(output, label) # size = (batch_size,)
  loss = losses.sum() / batch_size
  # =========== do on CPU ============
  mean = loss.item()
  var = losses.pow(2).sum().item() / batch_size - mean**2
  # ============ BP ================
  loss.backward()
  #gradient update
```

will the backward() on GPU wait for CPU computation to finish? Is there a way to do backward() and CPU computation in parallel?

Comment: I think you will find the [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) getting in your way

Answer (score 0):

It doesn’t do both computations at the same time. There is no exposed mechanism to do it parallely. (there is an advanced mechanism using CUDA streams that allows to do this in pytorch, but it is too error-prone for most users)

Comment: But isn't the torch.dataloader already hide the CPU data processing time in the GPU Back-propagation time? Like this blog said: https://www.sagivtech.com/2017/09/19/optimizing-pytorch-training-code/